# How do I add legend to SwiftChart library

Tags: ios, swift, charts, legend, swiftcharts

I am currently using [SwiftChart library](https://github.com/i-schuetz/SwiftCharts). I would like to add legend to a multi line chart. I cannot find if there is a way to do this. Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The legends are in a separate repository: https://github.com/i-schuetz/ChartLegends

Comment: I understand your justification for not including a default. I already started implementing a custom legend. I was just hoping for a default. Anyways I will make a feature request in Github, maybe others might like the idea of some form of default. 

Thank you for your response!